# array length not returning to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I'm trying to work out the length of an array :

```
$('input:checkbox[name="promoOn[]"]').click( function(){
  var attributes = [];
  $('input:checkbox[name="promoOn[]"]:checked').each(function(index) { 
    attributes.push($(this).val());
    $('#promo-on-total').html(attributes.length);
  });       
});
```

For some reason the array.length does not return to 0?
Here are the results:

```
Checkbox 1, checked = array.length = 1
Checkbox 2, checked = array.length = 2
Checkbox 2, unchecked = array.length = 2
Checkbox 1, unchecked = array.length = 1 (not 0???)
```

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: post the code where you are poping the items from the array

Comment: Is it me or when you unchecked checkbox 2 the array.length is not decremented ?

Comment: `var attributes = [];` will re-initialize the array ? isn't ? means on every click this will have `0` length. So decrement is not needed.

Comment: @Charles I strongly suspect that's a typo, it should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running through all checked checkboxes and updating the length value in the `promo-on-total`div there, but once you uncheck all checkboxes the loop isn't executed anymore (so the value isn't updated).

This will give you what you expect I think:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="promoOn[]"]').click( function(){
  var checkedValues = [];
  $('input:checkbox[name="promoOn[]"]:checked').each(function(index) {
    checkedValues.push($(this).val());
  });

  $('#promo-on-total').html(checkedValues.length);        
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FQqBT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think with this code it will be better.

```
$('input:checkbox[name="promoOn[]"]').click( function(){
  $('#promo-on-total').html($('input:checkbox[name="promoOn[]"]:checked').size());
});
```

The problem comes when you unchecked a checkbox, $('input:checkbox[name="promoOn[]"]:checked') is empty so the html content $('#promo-on-total') is not update.

I do a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/uvhjL/).